# Expires headers on an Amazon EC2 with Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I'm working with a client who has a Wordpress installation (via Bitnami) set up on an Amazon EC2.  I didn't put this together, and for background I am a Front-end Developer who is used to cPanel and has limited knowledge for the command line.

I'm trying to modify the expires headers to improve the speed of the client's site. Following this tutorial (http://www.theitbaby.com/wordpress/2013/10/14/optimizing-bitnami-for-pagespeed-insights-and-gtmetrix/) I was looking for the htaccess.conf file in my opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/ folder, however none existed.  Do I make my changes in the httpd-app.conf file?

Alternatively I saw a few other resources out there with a line to include the htaccess.conf file added to httpd-app.conf - something like

```
Include /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf
```

Do I add this to the httpd-app.conf file and then create htaccess.conf and work there?  Sorry for the confusion, just looking for some direction as I try to do my typical performance boost work.

Answer (score 0):

So the option what you are describing: creating and htaccess.conf file and then adding it as an `Include` statement in the httpd-app.conf file under `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/` is correct.

Make sure your `Include` statement is within the `Directory` directive and in the `htaccess.conf` file you don't need to have the `Directory` directive:

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
...
Include /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf
...
</Directory>
```

You can also add the pagespeed configs directly to the `http-app.conf` file if you'd like to inside the `Directory` directive too.

There's another option, but not necessarily popular if you have access to the main apache configuration files. You can create a `.htaccess` file under `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs` and put your pagespeed statements there. In this care you need the following statement preconfigured by the sysadmin in the `http-app.conf` file.

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
...
AllowOverride All
...
</Directory>
```

You can read more about `.htaccess` here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried what you described here - however I'm still not able to see any effect from my adding the expires headers.  I'm able to SSH into the instance and restart apache (since I enabled the expires module in httpd.conf), but when I follow your instructions above and add expires headers to the new htaccess.conf file, I never see any effect.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you enable the module ?  `LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so`